# find $\ \mathbb{Q}^\text{o}$( interior of $\mathbb{Q}$) in $\mathbb{R}$ in the following cases

Tags: general-topology

Find $\ \mathbb{Q}^\text{o}$( interior of $\mathbb{Q}$) in $\mathbb{R}$ in the following cases

$1. \mathbb{R}$ equipped  with  co-finite  topology

$2. \mathbb{R}$ endowed with the  co-countable topology

My attempt : I know  in usual Topology  that  interior will be $\emptyset$  but here I'm confused in co-finite and co- countable topology

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if $X \subset\mathbb Q$ then $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R\setminus X$.  So $\mathbb R\setminus X$ is not finite nor countable so $X$ is not open in either the cofinite or cocountable topologies,  and there are no open subsets in those topologies of $\mathbb Q$.  And so the interior is the union of all open subsets of $\mathbb Q$ and there are no open subsets... The interiors is empty.

Comment: But Correct me if I am wrong.  The interior of $\mathbb I = $ the set of irrationals is the the set of irrationals in the cocountable topology.  $\mathbb I \subset \mathbb I$ and $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb I = \mathbb Q$ which is countable so $\mathbb I$ is open and so $\mathbb I\subset $union of all open subsets of $\mathbb I\subset \mathbb I$ so $\mathbb I^{o} = \mathbb I$.  (But of course that isn't what we asked.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interior of $\mathbb{Q}$ is the biggest open set contained in $\mathbb{Q}$.

In the first case, $\mathcal{U}$ is open if $\mathcal{U} = \emptyset$ or $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathcal{U}$ is finite.

Assume $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is open. Since $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ is not finite, then $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathcal{U}$ won't be. So the only possibility is for $\mathcal{U}$ to be the empty set.

The proof is very similar with the co-countable topology.

Answer (score 1):

For both topologies, a non-empty set is open if and only if it contains some non-empty open set (exercise). Since $\Bbb Q$ isn't open in either, it has empty interior.